# O que vem a ser uma função binary-safe? E quais suas aplicações?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Estava navegando pelo manual do [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php) quando me deparei com a seguinte nota sobre a função `str_replace`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Nota: Esta função é binary-safe.

Dei uma [pesquisada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=binary-safe) aqui na rede e não achei nada a respeito.

**O que vem a ser uma função binary-safe? E quais suas aplicações?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicamente significa que ela vai funcionar com qualquer sequência de *bytes*.

Se puser caracteres de controle, `"\n"`, ou caractere nulo `"\0"`, ela não vai ter nenhum problema em fazer a substituição.

Exemplo:

```
$str1 = 'quebra'.chr(0).'de'.chr(0).'linha';
$str2 = str_replace( chr(0), "\n", $str1 );
```

Isto funciona perfeitamente.

Em PHP em geral as funções são, pois internamente o PHP associa os dados a uma espécie de "variável" interna que guarda o tamanho.

Em algumas linguagens por exemplo, em vez do tamanho ser armazenado, o que indica o fim da string é o caractere nulo `"\0"` (que no PHP é devolvido pelo `chr(0)`), o que seria um exemplo de "não *binary safe*".

Note que isto são apenas decisões de arquitetura, é tarefa do programador conhecer a linguagem e resolver conforme necessário. Simplesmente se precisar de uma string *binary safe* em C, basta fazer como o PHP faz internamente: armazenando o tamanho dos dados, em vez de indicar com um caractere específico.